# What is the best way to handle data-intensive requests with React and Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The bulk of my page is essentially a list of 40-100~ish components, each containing about 11 KB of data (in JSON format). The problem is that 100 times 11 KB makes 1.1 MB, which seems to be a little too memory-intensive to store in the Redux state for browsers on older mobile devices. It makes my gorgeous CSS animations look choppy and buttons take about a second to toggle on/off state.

Because each component is exactly 148px tall, my first thought was to use a virtual list (Virtuoso) which only renders as many items at a time as can fit on the screen (which is like 5-8 tops). This made the first time render much faster, but did nothing to make animations smoother, which definitely confirmed it's mostly a memory issue.

So, if I can't store and keep all my data in the state object, then I need to do something similar to Virtuoso and only keep as much data as I need to render the current screen. Now, I'm not exactly sure how Redux works internally, but if the state is immutable, doesn't that mean that everything that ever goes there stays there? And wouldn't that mean I'm trying to do something impossible, or at the very least anti-pattern?

Oh, and to make things worse, the data will need to be updated every 3 seconds, which means a component will sometimes disappear, only to reappear with the next update. I haven't tested how this would affect Virtuoso scrolling yet, but I don't exactly expect perfect plug-and-play behaviour.

I would appreciate ideas on how to solve this with redux and (possibly) its middleware, since it's the only architecture I'm familiar with atm and switching to e.g. Flux would mean having to learn it from scratch AND rewrite about 2000 lines of redux code.

Comment: Immutable just means that you can't (should not) mutate the current object, but the reducer it there to build a new state, which can use shallow copies of the old state whenever it doesn't change. So you could create a new array, and add to it. `{ ...state, yourList: [...state.yourList, ...newListItems] }`

Comment: Ideally, you should provide a [mcve] of the flow you're using right now so someone can point to places you could improve it. But even then, it would probably be better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you fetch each component's data when it is mounted? This is probably a good place to use redux-thunk, as you can define actions that would make calls to your api and dispatch updates with the response.

Comment: @Brian This is a little tricky, since currently the component gets unmounted once the user scrolls past it. Theoretically I can, but I feel it would lead to too many unnecessary requests, unless I scrap the virtual list and use endless scrolling instead. Which would eventually lead to the same problem I have now, how to store 100 live components in the memory.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I'm trying to figure out how to show an example, but without using my API and crafting the same animation intensive layout it doesn't really approach the scale of the problem I have. Unless I link to my actual project page, which is sort of proprietary. :[

Comment: You should be able to conditionally dispatch requests, based on if the data already exists in the store. If you have access to the api, and can add cache-control headers to the response that is an even better solution.

Comment: What I meant is, share the flow for one component, with mocked data, without the intensive rendering. We just need to see how you're managing the data before we can say where to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used Virtuoso, react-virtualized or react-window, but this looks like an issue that you can tackle with one of those libraries.

Do other parts of your React application care about the data you are rendering in the list?

- If not, put the data in this component's local state and not in Redux.
- If they do, maybe try to set this huge list in localStorage when the component mounts, unset it when it unmounts, and use the component's local state to select start / end indexes to pick a slice of the data.

See also: https://blog.jakoblind.no/is-using-a-mix-of-redux-state-and-react-local-component-state-ok/

Comment: Thank you! Yes, unfortunately the entire page is centred around the data. I hadn't thought about `localStorage`, it's a good idea that's worth a try. Thanks for your time again :)